# Java7 PropertyEditors registered via ThreadGroupContext

Tags: java, java-7

I found out that `PropertyEditorManager` registers/finds editors per `ThreadGroupContext` basis, not per global registry as prior to Java7.

And Java7 every time creates a new ThreadGroupContext for a new `ThreadGroup`. Thus PropertyEditorFinder (which actually registers/finds editors) is again new.

Java uses predefined editors for some classes (`Byte`, `Long`, etc) and registers them in `PropertyEditorFinder` at `ctor`). Let's say I want to register my own `PropertyEditor` for some predefined class (i.e. Long). It's easy to do in Java6, but in Java7, each time threads are created within new `ThreadGroup` I lost my editor.

So could you please tell me  is there any solution to handle in a nice manner which editors are created for a new `ThreadGroup` in Java7? If face some issue and how do you overcome it?

P.S. I guess I should apologize for my English =)

P.P.S. `ThreadGroupContext` is a replacement for `AppContext`. And I was hoping that implementation of creating contexts would be similar: both use mapping between `ThreadGroup` to context (`AppContext` in java 6, `ThreadGroupContext` in java 7). And java 6 uses the same `AppContext` for new `ThreadGroup` as for its parent. In other words `AppContext` is used for the whole `ThreadGroup` tree in a jvm. But unfortunately creating of `ThreadGroupContext` is different - it is simply a new context for a new group. So the question is automatically resolved if one day `ThreadGroupContext` will use the same creating technique.

Comment: I have the same problem with PropertyEditorManager and I haven't found  solution yet..

Answer (score 1):

If you had a class with a FQPN of java.lang.Long, you just need to implement a class called java.lang.LongEditor and distribute it with your application. In general, just implement a class that has the name of the class you want to edit with Editor appended to the end of it, and Java should find it automatically